# How to use the tags specific-tag and tagging tags here in meta? Do we need all of them?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tag-synonyms, tagging

I've tagged [I think that we have no good tags for solar-system-evolution or asteroid-formation or asteroid-evolution. Should we?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/648/7982) with [tags](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags), [specific-tag](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-tag) and [tagging](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) because I don't know which ones to use and none of them have any guidance.

Interestingly, mine is the only question tagged with [tagging](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) though I do not think I've just created it. Usually tags with no questions fade from view in a day or so, no?

**Question:** Anyway, how shall we use all of these tags, do we need all of them, should some be combined?

Comment: Some or all of these may be auto-generated meta tags.

Comment: I think they are suggestions of helpful tags for the site. It'd be nice if they had more clarity, but I think they're left general so each site can define them as necessary.