# Tags "planetary-atmosphere" vs. "atmosphere"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

While looking for tags without any definition (in order to suggest one), I came across the tag [`planetary-atmosphere`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-atmosphere) vs. [`atmosphere`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere) with 17 vs. 173 hits (as of February 11, 2021). My understanding is, that it is good practicse to minimize the number of tags, if somehow possible. **What do you think about setting all `planetary-atmosphere` to the more general tag `atmosphere`?**

For quite a few of the 173 hits, we actually have two tags `atmosphere` and the name of a planet (which would imply `planetary-atmosphere`). No information would be lost, if we would make sure that the 17 questions currently tagged `planetary-atmosphere` are changed to being `atmosphere`-tagged plus having  additionally either a planet name tag, or `exoplanet` or `planets`.

Answer (score 5):

> **Update:** There's a catch to being able to do this right away. See discussion in the comments.

These definitely should be merged. The only reason I could see for having a distinction would be for distinguishing between [Earth] atmospheric effects on observation and the study of atmospheres on other planets. That said, [atmosphere](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere) is currently being used for other planets, so there really is no distinction. If there's no opposition, I'll go ahead and merge these.

Comment: `+1` I'd say go for it. I use [`atmospheric-effects`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmospheric-effects) when I ask about astronomical aspects of Earth's atmosphere, so for questions about atmospheres other than those about looking through them with telescopes, this sounds fine. Do you have an option to choose planetary-atmosphere as the "main" name of the tag, or will it automatically be atmosphere because it's been used much more ofthen?

Comment: @uhoh I'll make planetary-atmosphere the main one.

Comment: okay that's great!

Comment: @uhoh Actually, on second thought, I may not be able to do that. The [tag:atmosphere] tag includes brown dwarf and stellar atmsophere questions.

Comment: hmm... I wonder if it's too many to convert to [`stellar-atmospheres`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-atmospheres)? Maybe over a few days they could be edited?

Comment: @uhoh I can't tell exactly how many there are. It seems probably between 20-50.

Comment: @uhoh It looks like there are also some that need to be retagged [tag:atmospheric-effects].

Comment: I see. It's lunar new year here and everything shuts down for a week. I'm happy to go through them and do that (convert where appropriate) over a period of a few days if it seems like a good idea.

Comment: @uhoh If you want to take on that effort, just let me know when you're done and then I'll do the merge.

Comment: @uhoh So to be clear, you just need to retag stellar atmosphere and atmospheric effects questions, and then you can leave the rest for me to merge.

Comment: Sorry, is this a different way to say the same thing: For all questions with the atmosphere tag that are *not about planetary atmospheres* remove the atmosphere tag. Then if they need stellar atmosphere or atmospheric effects tags, add them.

Comment: @uhoh Yes, that's what I mean. :) Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I basically have to script myself to get anything done these days :-)

Comment: @uhoh No worries if you haven't, but have you had a chance to look at these yet?

Comment: yikes no, will do today and update you. I (obviously) have time just not the necessary management skills to go with it. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer w/summary for today

Comment: I'm done! 1) atmosphere can be merged into planetary-atmosphere, 2) none of the questions in either one are now related to stellar atmospheres except the ones also containing that tag (for some reason a few need both), and 3) I'll write a tag wiki excerpt for atmospheric-effects that reflects all the questions that are in it now.

Comment: @uhoh Ok, merge and synonym complete. Make sure to put a "see also" in the excerpt for planetary atmosphere that refers to stellar-atmosphere and atmospheric-effects.

Comment: Great! I've just added two new short excerpts: [1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags/stellar-atmospheres/info), [2](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags/planetary-atmosphere/info)

Comment: @uhoh Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that [atmosphere](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere) and [planetary-atmosphere](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-atmosphere) tags will be merged and called planetary-atmosphere, so I will treat them as one in my summary below.

I've set about the following scripted task:

> - For all questions with the atmosphere *or planetary-atmosphere* tags that are not about planetary atmospheres remove those tags.
> - Then if they need stellar atmosphere or atmospheric effects tags, add them.
> - Ping moderators when complete so that the merge can execute.

To that end I've processed <s>the 50 most recent</s> ALL THE questions tagged with either (or both).

Here are all my final results after the second wave:

#### changed to atmospheric-effects

- [Understanding energy loss in a telescope aperture due to atmospheric dispersion](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40804/7982)
- [Source of red in earth's photographs](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40190/7982)
- [Why is blue light extincted more strongly than red?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34835/7982)
- [What is the horizontal distance needed to observe an object just as badly as if it where in space at the zenith?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34198/7982)
- [Why is it that night has a almost a bluish tint to it instead of red?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29175/7982)  (paused here)
- [Public Data Set on Atmospheric Absorbtion / Extinction](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13385/7982)
- [How much clearer are stars in earths orbit?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18697/7982)
- [Could spy satellites use laser guide stars (for adaptive optics)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11454/7982)
- [Looking at ourselves with a powerful telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27567/7982)
- [Why is moon light not the same color as sunlight?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26780/7982)
- [What is tilt anisoplanatism for Laser-guide-star usage in adaptive optic systems?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25170/7982)
- [Do the gases in the Earth's atmosphere affect the color of a lunar eclipse?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/24804/7982)
- [Does the summit of a small mountain offer better seeing?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16179/7982)
- [Can you see city lights on the Moon from Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14631/7982)
- [Why can't moon light (reflected sun light) turn the sky blue?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14102/7982)
- [Oldest Reference to Astronomical Seeing](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13386/7982)
- [Why doesn't the Moonrise appear red when viewed from orbit?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11180/7982)
- [Around what apparent magnitude can the naked eye observe an object during full moon](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10322/7982)
- [How many stars can be seen naked eye from outside the atmosphere? How dense is the "sky" from there?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/8139/7982)
- [Effect of the absence of atmospheric refraction to sun rise and sunset times](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/8054/7982)
- [Does the earth's atmosphere act as a spherical lens and refract light from space?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2234/7982)
- [How could a hobbyist astronomer determine apparent magnitude of a star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/331/7982)

#### changed to stellar-atmosphere

- [Would the electron cyclotron-maser emission mechanism affect Proxima b's ability to retain an atmosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40208/7982)
- [Is there any synthetic spectrum software for neutron star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38449/7982)
- [Is the atmosphere of neutron star solid, liquid or gaseous state?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34496/7982)
- [A neutron star without a flat surface and an atmosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29997/7982)
- [Why does the adiabatic exponent decrease at the ionization zones?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27769/7982)
- [Does the Sun have any atmosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22453/7982)

#### removed atmosphere only

- [If the Earth circled a red dwarf/giant or a brown dwarf, would its sky still look blue?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40129/7982)
- [Ladakh India where the moon (Ramadan moon) is sighted but not in rest of India](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36300/7982)
- [How can neutron stars have gaseous atmospheres?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14988/7982)

#### now have BOTH atmosphere & stellar-atmosphere

- [Do brown dwarfs have stripes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39410/7982)

#### now have BOTH atmosphere & atmospheric-effects

- [When and where are we exposed to most cosmic radiation?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32930/7982)
- [Is it possible to see Saturn from Titan's surface, day and night?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27579/7982)
- [Scattered Intensity of Light vs Angles of Incidence and Emission](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26009/7982)
- [Are the darker blue/black areas in this picture what the atmosphere of Jupiter looks like without clouds?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22723/7982)
- [What are reliable resources for weather and all other atmospheric obstructions?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22045/7982)
- [Is Earth unique in its fairly clear atmosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12531/7982)
- [How accurate are rederings of something entering Earth's atmosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11005/7982)
- [Energetics of Titans Tholin haze](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/7823/7982)
- [Can we hear something on Venus, Mars and Titan?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/5938/7982)

#### added planetary-atmosphere only

- [Refraction by Saturn's atmosphere - how dense is it here?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16703/7982)