# Is it a good idea to create a much-needed tag and retag (almost) every post related to it to include this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, retagging

Recently, I created the tag [hr-diagram](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hr-diagram) as there are many questions regarding it.  I went ahead and edited a few questions to include this new tag. Would it be a good idea to retag all the 82 (and counting) results that include the phrase *HR diagram*, or should we keep them as is and let new questions trickle in with this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually retagging more than 4-5 questions in a big batch is discouraged because unfortunately it clutters the active questions feed. But if you want to slowly work them in over time, I don't see anything wrong with that. Since you use an abbreviation you should probably create a tag excerpt that describes the tag and spells out Hertzsprung-Russell diagram.

Comment: Definitely agree with what called2voyage said. I think typical advice is to also do those batches on weekends where activity is low, meaning that you're not taking up space from as many recently-active questions.

Comment: @fasterthanlight [here's an example](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/7982). I tried to do it in a few "waves" rather than all at once for the reasons mentioned above. I found it helpful to work in chronological order (use "newest" when doing searches) and to keep a list of which posts were modified, just in case it's necessary to reverse something or make a further change in the future, as well as to keep track of progress and to allow people to yell at me if I did something wrong and to defend myself if they say I did but I didn't :-) (It's a big undertaking/site impact)