# Do we need a tag for merging? I struggled to find something suitable for supermassive black hole mergers in galaxy collisions

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, specific-tag, tagging

I wanted to add a tag like `black-hole-merger` to [How do we know that supermassive black holes can gain mass by means other than merging with other supermassive black holes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43821/7982) but couldn't find anything close.

Considering the number of gravitational wave questions we have and the ever-expanding observational capabilities of current and future devices, mergers are going to be regularly posted questions.

Would `black-hole-merger` or `mergers` or `merging-events` or something similar be a good idea? Should it be specific to a pair of black holes? What about a black hole/neutron star or two neutron star merger?

Comment: I think a general merger tag would be useful.

Comment: I am wondering in how far the [tag:collision]-tag is overlapping here.

Comment: @B--rian for questions [also tagged black-hole](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision+black-hole), very little.

Comment: @B--rian I've just asked [What is the difference between the terms collision and merger? How are they used differently in Astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44256/7982) I think that the collision that formed Earth's Moon and two black holes or neutron stars or plain-old stars spiraling in to each other eventually forming one object are too different to share the same tag. I've been "proactive" and created the `merger` tag.

Comment: @B--rian I think that once we can articulate the difference I can do a [retagging campaign](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/7982) and tidy things up, but I'm open to arguments to the contrary.