# One tag for LIGO, Virgo and KAGRA or three, or none?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

We have

- [ligo](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ligo): **14** questions

> Questions about the Laser Interferometer Gravitational-Wave Observatory (LIGO), a large-scale physics experiment and observatory to detect cosmic gravitational waves.

but nothing for the two other gravitational wave detectors on Earth

- [Virgo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgo_interferometer)
- [KAGRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KAGRA)

nor the observational/instrumentational collaboration of all three.

What's a good way to address these three related observatories with tagging? One? Three? None, and how to be proactive in our thinking considering that space-based gravitational wave detectors may come on line and in some cases work together with these Earth-based observatories in the future? (e.g. [LISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Interferometer_Space_Antenna) and/or [DECIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deci-hertz_Interferometer_Gravitational_wave_Observatory))

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the [gravitational-wave-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravitational-wave-astronomy) tag that hasn't really caught on yet. It seems to capture the case where the topic involves collaboration quite well.

Comment: so for example [gravitational-wave-astronomy] for questions involving any/all GW observatories, measurements and data analysis/reduction, and [gravitational-waves] for the phenomenon itself (e.g. how they occur and propagate) and sort-of a moratorium on tags for individual GW observatories? I think that can work. We have tags for "polyglots" like Hubble and JWST because they are so prolific and different and have such a diversity of applications goodies inside and [space-telescope] for all the rest but I agree one tag might be enough.

Comment: If in five years someone wanted to look for LISA they can search "[gravitational-wave-astronomy] lisa is:question". But doing this will require going through 164 questions currently tagged [gravitational-waves] and deciding which should have [gravitational-wave-astronomy], which will be a retagging campaign similar to [this one](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/7982). If this seems to be a solution others agree with I can propose a new question along that line describing the "algorithm" to decide which gets which, and if folks then agree again I can volunteer to do it.

Comment: @uhoh Yes, that's what I had in mind. Thanks for spelling that out.