# We've been using the [gravitational-waves] tag for 10 years, do we really also need [gravitational-wave-astronomy]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-tag, tagging

We have had this tag since 2014:

- [gravitational-waves](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravitational-waves) **181** questions

> Waves in spacetime formed by the acceleration of massive bodies. A passing wave causes spacetime to be stretched and squashed by a very small amount. Typically we can only detect the most energic gravitational events such as black hole mergers.

About 1.5 years ago a second tag was added with a pretty low usage rate:

- [gravitational-wave-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravitational-wave-astronomy) **7** questions

> The gravitational-wave-astronomy tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

I think it's unlikely that we'll have questions about gravitational waves that are not related to Astronomy in some way. I don't see how having both tags and having each question author grapple with how to decide if they should use one, the other, or both.

Should they be merged, or some other action taken to consolidate back to a single tag?

---

Note that when we want to narrow down the aspect of gravitational waves the question addresses, we generally add one or more of the following:

- [observational-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observational-astronomy) **1,297** questions

> Questions about the techniques and practice of observing the night sky.

- [observatory](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observatory) **71** questions

> Questions regarding structures designed to aid in the observation of astronomical objects.

- [instruments](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruments) **53** questions

> The instruments tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [cosmology](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology) **518** questions

> Questions about the origin, history, evolution and fate of the Universe.

- [time-domain-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-domain-astronomy) **23** questions

> The time-domain-astronomy tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [observation-campaign](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/observation-campaign) **8** questions

> The observation-campaign tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the [gravitational-wave-astronomy] tag is redundant. I've merged it into [gravitational-waves]

Comment: [Another One Bites the Dust](https://youtu.be/VbN-YxUFITI)

Comment: The use of the [tag:gravitational-wave-astronomy] tag was first suggested (incorrectly?) by a moderator here: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/846/18054, adding a different tag was discussed in the comments there. It's important to note that early gravitation wave **observations** did not utilize "astronomy" but are **physic**ally based, such as [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO). Later "[Pulsar Timing Arrays](https://www.epta.eu.org/gravitational-waves.html)", which do utilize astronomy, were developed to study extremely low frequency gravity waves; previously undetectable.