# What is the best way to tag questions about Xuntian, the Chinese Survey Space Telescope?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tagging, tag-synonyms

What is the best tag for China's Xuntian, i.e. the [Chinese Survey Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuntian)?

It's schedule to be launched this year in the Tiangong space station orbit (but phased away from it) and the questions here have already begun.

- [How will China's Xuntian space telescope use its Terahertz capability? THz Spectroscopy? Imaging? Something else?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/53065/7982)
- [Details on the telescope(s) on the Chinese Space Station 天和](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43706/7982)

For me, an important feature of tags is that they should appear as autocomplete options when people start typing the words they think of, so typing either "Xuntian" or "Chinese" should ideally make the tag appear, with a name that makes it obvious.

One option is of course xuntian-chinese-survey-space-telescope but there may or may not be issues of character count.

**Question:** What is the best way to tag questions about Xuntian, the Chinese Survey Space Telescope?

Answer (score 3):

Tag it with [csst], as this tag already exists.

We have tags for specific telescopes that use the name of the telescope or mission:  Eg [gaia] or [chandra].  Hubble is treated differently, as [hubble-telescope] probably to disambiguate from Edwin Hubble.

You may create tag synonyms [xuntian] and [chinese-survey-space-telescope] if you have a score of 5 or more on the [csst] tag.    Both fit in the 35-character limit. But this is probably jumping the gun. Nobody has the required score yet, and this isn't likely to attract hundreds of questions that would need to manually retagged, so let's not overthink this.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good! I'm just curious; is there any downside to being proactive about synonymization?  I have a giant blind spot when it comes to "tagging theory"; the reason I suggested it is that some folks may not start typing x..u..n... and failing to see an autocomplete may start a new tag like csst or chinese... and then we have questions split over two tags that someone has to corral back together later. Where's the down side to being proactive and avoiding that scenario? Why should proactivity and foward-thinking behavior be discouraged?

Comment: The S.E. model of tags makes creating synonyms quite hard.  Tags are a big part of Stack Overflow, but they less significant on quieter sites.  In terms of numbers, we have 6 questions tagged [chandra] I'd expect a similar number about xuntian

Comment: ...not counting the questions that get mistagged. Does synonymization much of an intrinsic cost that makes it "expensive" to use them for anything except tags with a large number of questions? Isn't [tracking down and fixing mis-tagged questions *ex post facto*](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/7982) more work than avoiding it in cases where the helpful synonyms (for autocomplete) are pretty easy to identify (i.e. ounce of prevention...)?

Comment: I don't disagree, feel free to propose the synonym, if you want to.  I won't judge you if you don't

Comment: I've made some edits, because I noticed that csst already exists.  Also to mention the score 5 or higher on a tag that is required even to propose a synonym.