# An [ultraviolet] tag to go with our [gamma-rays], [x-ray], [visible-light], [infrared], and [radio] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

#### We have these electromagnetic tags

- [gamma-rays](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-rays) **11** questions

> The gamma-rays tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [x-ray](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray) **36** questions

> Questions regarding the second-shortest wavelength of light.

- [visible-light](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) **22**  questions

> Questions regarding a wavelength of light ranging from 380 to 700 nm. This is the spectrum that we can see.

- [infrared](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrared) **43** questions

> Questions about infrared astronomy, both observations (in the broadest sense) and instruments. The infrared part of the electromagnetic spectrum has a longer wavelength than visible light, but shorter than sub-mm or radio waves.

- [radio](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) **34** questions

> Questions about the part of the electromagnetic spectrum with wave lengths longer than those of infrared radiation.

#### along with some electromagnetically honorable mentions:

- [cosmic-microwave-background](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmic-microwave-background) **117** questions

> Questions about is the electromagnetic radiation remnant from the early stage of the universe, also known as "relic radiation".

- [gamma-ray-bursts](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-ray-bursts) **32** questions

> Gamma ray bursts are flashes of gamma rays, produced by extremely powerful explosions in distant galaxies. They are among the most powerful events in the universe

- [radio-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-astronomy) **304** questions

> Questions about observations performed in the radio frequency range of the electromagnetic spectrum.

- [radio-telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-telescope) **98** questions

> Questions related to the instruments used to perform observations in the radio frequency range.

- [fast-radio-bursts](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-radio-bursts) **11** questions

> Use for questions about fast radio burst (FRB) or blitzars. Related tags: "pulsar", "magnetar", "radio-astronomy".

#### But nothing in the ultra-violet.

After I asked [Can we see atomic positronium lines in space? What could be learned from it and what are current challenges to doing so?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/50405/7982) and added the [infrared](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrared) I noticed there was no tag for ultraviolet to go with it.

So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Should we have an [ultraviolet] tag to go with our [gamma-rays], [x-ray], [visible-light], [infrared] and [radio] tags?

Answer (score -2):

It seems like we could benefit from a [multiwavelength](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiwavelength) tag to capture observations beyond the visible spectrum of light. I propose leaving [radio-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-astronomy), [visible-light](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light), and [infrared](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrared) separate since these are significant areas of interest, but the rest ([gamma-rays](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-rays), [x-ray](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray), and the proposed [ultraviolet](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultraviolet)) should be made synonyms of [multiwavelength](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiwavelength).

I think [radio](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) should have already been made a synonym of [radio-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-astronomy).

Comment: In all my years in Space and Astronomy I've never seen you make a call I didn't agree with or at least go with. But throwing three different fields of observational astronomy into a bin who's name doesn't even make sense seems like a bad idea to me. It seems arbitrary; why not put radio and infrared in there as well? And the name makes no sense for all the questions have no "multi" aspect.  I also don't understand why questions about gamma rays, X-rays or ultraviolet should no longer be searchable by using a tag. How are these tags causing harm? Where is the benefit from "multi"?

Comment: There was also a discussion, I think between someone else and I, years ago about [radio], though it could have been with someone else, and at that time I questioned it and the other person said there was a distinction between it and the other "radios". I'm all for getting rid of [radio].

Comment: @uhoh My rationale here has to do with the low usage of these tags. I think they're likely to gain more attention collectively. Others are of course welcome to express their disagreement. I got the "multiwavelength" suggestion from academic papers which used this as a technical way to express observations that included the beyond-visible spectrum, but I would also be ok with a [tag:beyond-visible] tag if people thought that would be more comprehensible.

Comment: Beyond is certainly better than multi. It's not something one would start typing, but if - by using synonymization - the autocomplete would still show the catch-all tag when someone started typing ult.. or xra... or gam... at least the tagging part works. But if I understand correctly, one would no longer be able to search for gamma-ray or x-ray or ultra-violet by using their tags. As for a trend for lower usage increasing energy above visible, I think it has to do with the Earth's atmosphere and instrumentation; these are relegated (mostly) to space telescopes, planes and suborbital flights.

Comment: and by the increasing difficulty in imaging with payloads of limited size and cost. *This could change in the future!* It's not that these bands are ultimately of any less consequence than the lower energies, it's just that (in my opinion) *to date* they have had lower quality (resolution, total hours of observation). Some might see all processes and observations above visible being relegated to a single tag as a slight or a bias. Even Gilligan's Island went the other way - converting "and the rest" to "the professor and Marry Anne" in the second season. :-)

Comment: Anyway, I worry that loosing specific searchability by these three tags (ultra, x-ray, gamma) permanently in this specific case should be considered carefully, especially if these fields grow in the future.

Comment: @uhoh Those are all good points, and I'd be happy to see another answer make a good case based on those. I just want to make sure we're creating something that is actually going to be maintained.